# How to assign action to top toolbar in tab fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-tabs

I presently have the result as:

[image]

But I wish for the mail symbol to be present on the top toolbar (orange). 
The view as seen is a tabbed view that exists within a navigation drawer.

How can I allow the mail symbol to be placed within the top toolbar?

*Tabbed fragment onCreateView:*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_tab_layout, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) x.findViewById(R.id.event_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.events_menu);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return x;

}
```

*Event_tab_layout.xml:*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/event_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

activity_main.xml (the orange bar source):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="blank" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding exactly what you want, but I think it's pretty clearly outlined in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html

Comment: You don't need don't Toolbar in your Fragment. Remove it and action will go to main Toolbar.